# Getting Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception when FetchType is Eager

Tags: hibernate, lazy-initialization

I know this is famous Exception, but I haven't been able to find a way to resolve this.

```
@Entity
public class Action {
@Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;

@NotBlank
private String name;

@Any(metaColumn = @Column(name ="rule_type"),fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@AnyMetaDef(idType = "long",metaType = "string",metaValues = {@MetaValue(targetEntity = ScheduledRule.class,value = "scheduledRule"),
        @MetaValue(targetEntity = NagiosRule.class,value = "nagiosRule")})
@JoinColumn(name = "rule_id")
@Fetch(value = FetchMode.JOIN)
private Rule rule;
//few other lines of code not relevant here
} // end of class
```

The problem comes when I try to fetch the Action entity from the db using session API's, I get the following error:

> Method threw 'org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException' exception.
>   Cannot evaluate
>   flipkart.alert.rule.domain.NagiosRule_$$_jvst204_1e.toString().

I am not able to understand why is this happening, as I have only used FetchType as Eager.

Comment: Have you solved this?

Comment: No, haven't found a way yet.